# Sites transferindo suas perguntas para o StackOverflow em Português

Tags: debate, proposta-para-faq, comunidade

Todo mundo que já usou algum site da rede do Stack Exchange sabe como o software é muito bom para a troca de conhecimento e como a filosofia empregada garante que isso seja feito de forma saudável e objetiva.

Isso até fez uma das principais empresas de tecnologia transferir seu suporte à comunidade para a rede através do [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/).

Vários sites tem preferido essa plataforma para suas perguntas e respostas. Já temos uma transferência da comunidade **[Laravel Brasil](http://forum.laravel.com.br/viewtopic.php?id=1686)** para nosso StackOverflow em Português.

Isso é muito legal e vamos torcer para que o mesmo aconteça com outros sites.

Se você tem influência em alguma comunidade que pode se beneficiar usando essa plataforma e algum ponto está dificultando a transferência, não hesite em postar aqui para tentarmos facilitar a situação.

E aproveite esse *post* para colocar outros sites que preferiram migrar seu suporte ou troca de conhecimento para cá.

Comment: Nós da comunidade [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) e [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/support) do Brasil gostaríamos de preparar tudo para quando abrir o Beta usarmos o SO pt para suporte. A Xamarin usa isso no [SO en](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xamarin%20or%20monotouch%20or%20monodroid%20or%20xamarin.mac).

Ainda não temos data de abertura do beta público. Alguém sabe de algo? A pergunta sobre isso não tem nada mais concreto.

Comment: Excelente! Ia mesmo falar com o Rodrigo Kumpera que sei que trabalha lá e até como o Miguel que talvez fale um pouco de português em casa :) Está resolvido.

Comment: Acho ótimo, @AlexandreMarcondes! A resposta oficial sobre isso é que vamos para beta público [*provavelmente* até o fim de janeiro](http://meta.br.stackoverflow.com/questions/336/beta-privado-ate-quando/459#459).

Comment: Nós já estamos trabalhando nisso no Grupo Mono Brasil. No momento a Xamarin não vai dar suporte oficial em português, nós estamos querendo movimentar a comunidade mesmo. @bigown você usa o Mono? Olha a [comunidade no Google+](https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/103975842905139211056) com todos nossos links para agilizar isso.

Comment: @AlexandreMarcondes Diretamente ainda não. Já fucei um pouco no passado. Mas voltando a trabalhar com C#, é provável que trabalharei com ele também, principalmente agora que C# é a linguagem mais multiplataforma para os sistemas mainstreans :P

Answer (score 2):

É bom registrar que o pessoal do Laravel desistiu de usar o SOpt e reabriu o fórum deles. Alguns depoimentos a respeito, retirados [do próprio fórum](http://forum.laravel.com.br/viewtopic.php?id=1686):

> Fluxo da comunidade caiu depois que sugerimos a mudança pro Stack
>   Overflow =/
>
> Lá é legal e tal, mas não sei, será que não estamos "matando" uma boa
>   discussão e ajuda mútua que praticamos aqui?
>
> Será que compensa migrarmos a criação de questões pra lá? Aqui, ao
>   menos, temos uma comunidade focada. Lá fora tem Stack Overflow e nem
>   por isso os fóruns se privaram.
>
> Apenas uma reflexão. Qual o pensamento de vocês?

> Eu gostava mais quando era apenas o Forum aqui...acho fraco o fluxo do
>   br.stack.... Aqui é mais fácil acompanhar os tópicos pendentes,
>   pesquisar existentes, sei lá, pra mim o uso e praticidade do fórum é
>   maior do que o stackoverflow. Fora q as vezes a mesma questão feita
>   aqui, é respondida lá, ficando bagunçado.

> Sem contar a galerinha que fica dizendo como a pergunta deve ser feita
>   e respondida.
>
> Talvez não seja pro meu nível  hehehehe
>
> O fórum, show de bola!

Answer (score 1):

Não seria melhor esperar a etapa de beta público para fazer este tipo de coisa? Atualmente no beta privado, só entra quem confirmou na Area 51 ou quem for convidado por alguém que já está aqui.

Comment: Sim, mas tem gente fazendo isso, não vou impedir :) De qualquer forma, isso ocorrerá em poucos dias. Isso não é uma resposta, teria sido melhor colocar como comentário.

Comment: @bigown Você sabe de alguma coisa oficial sobre essa parte do "em poucos dias"? Me lembro de ter lido algo dizendo que este site demoraria mais que o normal para ir a public beta, por ser tão diferente. E que isso não ocorreria enquanto ainda houvesse coisa faltando traduzir.

Comment: @bfavaretto Pode até ser mesmo, essa foi mais por minha conta :)

Comment: Já convidei alguns da comunidade brasileira de lisp para vir :)