# Três perguntas amplas demais. O que fazer?

Tags: debate, qualidade, pergunta-específica

Um mesmo usuário postou em sequência três perguntas problemáticas. Em ordem cronológica:

- [Como faço para ler o registro das chamadas recebidas e efetuadas no iPhone utilizando o Xamarin?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2208/como-faco-para-ler-o-log-das-chamadas-recebidas-e-efetuadas-no-iphone-utilizando)
- [Ler registro de histórico de SMS no iPhone usando Xamarin](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2209/ler-log-do-sms-no-iphone-xamarin)
- [Ler arquivo contatos agenda iPhone usando Xamarin](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2210/ler-arquivo-contatos-agenda-iphone-xamarin)

Tem **muitos** problemas nessas três perguntas. A primeira, o bigown editou para dar pelo menos forma correta ao título, texto e tags (ao menos *formalmente*, era tudo o que se podia fazer). As outras duas ainda têm esses problemas. Mas o principal problema, comum às três, é que não dão nenhum tipo de detalhe. Simplesmente perguntam [como fazer X](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/105/sobre-esforco-em-perguntas-no-estilo-como-fazer-x). Não situam quem está lendo sobre tentativas já efetuadas, nem nos deixam perceber quanto o autor conhece sobre as tecnologias em questão (seria um principante? um especialista?). A forma e o tom das perguntas parecem pedir tutoriais como respostas – e tutoriais não se enquadram no formato deste site. Por isso eu as fecharia como

> **amplo demais**
>   Ou há muitas respostas possíveis ou boas respostas seriam muito longas para este formato. Acrescente detalhes para reduzir o conjunto de respostas ou isole uma questão que possa ser respondida em poucos parágrafos.

Duas delas receberam votos de fechamento como duplicatas da primeira (neste momento uma já está fechada). Não são duplicatas, são três perguntas totalmente distintas (além de vagas). Mas o fechamento como duplicata aponta para uma possível salvação: não são duplicatas, mas são claramente três componentes de um mesmo fim que o autor quer atingir. Talvez se ele fizesse uma única pergunta, dando mais contexto sobre o que está fazendo, pode sair uma resposta (geral) que aponte uma solução, e quem sabe seja útil para futuros visitantes.

Comment: Eu acho também muito ampla e acho q poderiam ser todas colocadas em uma única pergunta.

Comment: Essa discussão toda ajudou a mostrar uma tendencia de o pessoal aceitar tudo, coisa que eu já esperava do publico brasileiro, mas começou cedo demais. Espero que o pessoal mais experiente e que está mais acostumado com a filosofoa da Stack Exchange não se omita para não comprometer o nível do site. Começou a entortar cedo demais.

Comment: eu gostaria de entender como é possível colocar três perguntas em uma e ela ficar menos ampla

Comment: @clrod Não sei mais se seria uma boa solução neste caso (vide resposta do Alexandre Marcondes), mas a idéia era que as 3 juntas formassem uma pergunta totalmente diferente, que não fosse sobre os 3 pontos específicos e sim sobre o que está por trás deles.

Comment: @bfavaretto não sei se eu entendi o que você disse ou o que o Alexandre Marcondes disse eu li que ele queria 3 perguntas mesmo

Comment: @clrod Ele diz que queria 3 perguntas, e que elas são artificiais, por isso comentei que não sei mais se seria uma boa solução fundi-las. Eu havia pensado que uma única pergunta *talvez* funcionasse, caso houvesse um problema maior por trás delas, algo ligado à arquitetura da aplicação que faria uso dos 3 recursos. Mas só o autor poderia dizer se haveria esse problema maior, e criar uma pergunta única que fizesse sentido.

Answer (score 12):

Gente, eu gostaria de me manifestar pois eu me sinto como motivador disso tudo. O grupo do Mono Brasil (grupo de usuários e desenvolvedores Mono e Xamarin do Brasil) está começando a usar o StackOverflow como plataforma de suporte e base de conhecimento para futuras referências em português (Veja esta [discussão no meta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/139/sites-transferindo-suas-perguntas-para-o-stackoverflow-em-portugues#comment1020_139)).

Eu pedi para o usuário em questão abrir essas perguntas para iniciar o processo de uso do site para isso. Creio que seja melhor eu editar as perguntas para melhorá-las (vou fazer isso ainda hoje), mas como o @utluiz comentou, não é uma pergunta genérica nem muito aberta. São três coisas diferentes, porém relacionadas. Eu pedi para ele abrir três perguntas pois achei que seria melhor para a comunidade ter três perguntas específicas relacionadas do que uma pergunta com três respostas diferentes.

Quanto à questão de busca no Google e informações em outros lugares, creio que o grande objetivo do Stack Overflow em português existir não é por orgulho da língua ou para ficarmos traduzindo o site o original apenas, muito menos por patriotismo ou regionalismo. Para mim a idéia é dar acesso à respostas e conteúdo de qualidade para aqueles que não falam inglês e/ou não sabem o suficiente para entender a totalidade de um artigo em inglês.

Fechar uma pergunta porque tem resposta em inglês no Google não é a melhor opção, creio que se não há conteúdo em português é aí que nosso site deve entrar. Mesmo que o conteúdo seja básico ou fácil de encontrar em inglês.

Comment: Fico feliz que tenha vindo discutir isto aqui, e que seu grupo use o site como plataforma de suporte. De fato eu posso estar equivocado na minha posição de votar para fechar (tem pessoas que defendem esse tipo de pergunta, incluindo o Gabe, nosso moderador e representante oficial da rede Stack Exchange). O que notei foi que outros usuários também reprovaram as perguntas, o que acabou gerando discussão e uma certa desordem nas ações (votos para fechar por dois motivos diferentes). Estamos em um momento de definir o que vale no site, e essas perguntas surgiram como bons exemplo a se discutir.

Comment: Dito isto, eu pessoalmente não gosto desse estilo de pergunta – embora concorde com [a opinião de que elas podem tendem a ser úteis *a posteriori*](http://meta.br.stackoverflow.com/questions/105/sobre-esforco-em-perguntas-no-estilo-como-fazer-x/121#121), uma pergunta para me agradar geralmente precisa ser mais elaborada. Acredito que o legal do site é a troca de conhecimentos entre quem pergunta e quem responde. Ambos devem aprender algo, e perguntas nesse formato costumam dar a impressão de que a outra parte está pedindo uma "receita de bolo", não tem tanto interesse em aprender "de verdade".

Comment: Concordo com você @bfavaretto, só acho o seguinte. Há anos tenho sido instrutor em treinamentos e tirado dúvidas de várias tecnologias e linguagens aqui no Brasil. Não sei se é algo do brasileiro ou é geral mesmo, mas as perguntas mais comuns que eu encontro são facilmente encontráveis em inglês e são nesse formato de como faço X. Creio que infelizmente, ou felizmente - não sei ainda avaliar, vamos encontrar muitas dessas perguntas no site assim que ele for aberto publicamente. Pelo menos até que essas perguntas possam ser respondidas com outras que já estejam no site e sejam mais elaboradas.

Comment: Eu acho ótima sua vinda aqui pra discutir o problema, e realmente concordo com serem perguntas diferentes (ao menos da maneira que foi formulada). O que está faltando no meu ver, é uma explanação de alguma dificuldade que você tenha encontrado no processo, pois da forma que está, é praticamente "faça o serviço pra mim" e isso me dá uma preocupação extremamente grande com o futuro do site.

Answer (score 9):

Vou acrescentar algumas poucas coisas em relação às perguntas mas vou falar de um problema mais generalizado.

Concordo com o Alexandre Marcondes e o utluiz, principalmente com relação às buscas.

Pelo que eu sei, o Alexandre entende bem do assunto das perguntas e pode falar com propriedade sobre ele. Mesmo sem ter um *background* no assunto específico, pelo menos pelo currículo dele, o utluiz avaliou perfeitamente as perguntas.

Curiosamente podemos dar opiniões no SO sem escrever um palavra. Basta votar up. Down, para fechar, etc. Mas sem entender do assunto o voto é apenas uma opinião e não uma decisão consciente. Pior ainda quando a pessoa está dando um voto "*me too*", ou seja, "eu só quero participar de alguma forma, e já que algumas pessoas decidiram assim, vou no embalo." **Isso é um perigo**.

Claro que não vamos começar aceitar respostas do tipo *link only*. Mas nós temos um caso diferente aqui. E se a pessoa tem dificuldade de achar documentação por estar em inglês ou mesmo que tenha em português mas está em lugares mais obscuros do que costumam estar em inglês? Desde que a resposta tenha mais do um link e uma frase irrelevante, o conteúdo deveria ser bem-vindo aqui.

Quando as repostas deles postadas aqui praticamente não são votadas, me preocupa mais ainda. Parece que ninguém está vendo nada errado no que aconteceu.

Mas o problema ocorrido com essas perguntas é outro. Houve muita precipitação no seu tratamento. Vou destacar a [excelente resposta do mgibsonbr](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/482/como-lidar-com-perguntas-com-certo-grau-de-subjetividade/483#483) onde ele fala de que só conhecimento específico sobre o assunto tratado pode fazer um julgamento justo se a pergunta é boa ou não.

Peço a todos para não tomarem ações em cima de assuntos que não conhecem. O Alexandre Marcondes já falou um pouco sobre isso, não vou repetir.

## Primeira pergunta

Como poderia a resposta dada pelo Zuul em [Como faço para ler o registro das chamadas recebidas e efetuadas no iPhone utilizando o Xamarin?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2208/como-faco-para-ler-o-registro-das-chamadas-recebidas-e-efetuadas-no-iphone-utili) ser pior que a resposta do hernandes em [Envio de email funciona localmente mas não em servidor remoto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2204/envio-de-email-funciona-localmente-mas-nao-em-servidor-remoto)? Ambas dizem que o problema não pode ser resolvido por conta própria. Uma diz que só é possível fazendo *jailbreak* e a outra diz para contatar o provedor. A primeira é totalmente sobre desenvolvimento. A segunda há, no mínimo, dúvidas.

Então como pode haver decisão de fechar a primeira, horas depois da decisão de manter a segunda aberta?

Eu não gosto muito de perguntas desse tipo mas elas não causam muito mal também. Mas se o segundo exemplo vai ficar aberto, então essa pergunta também tem que ficar. Eu prefiro ela muito mais. É uma dúvida legítima diretamente ligada ao desenvolvimento de software e o fato de não ter uma resposta de como fazer, não a torna ruim por definição. Resolve um problema que pode ser útil para outros programadores tentando achar uma informação sobre isso. Não é um problema específico dele.

Aqui minha decisão vai depender da decisão sobre a outra pergunta discutida em [O que fazer com perguntas que podem parecer ser de desenvolvimento mas se revelam não ser?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/513/o-que-fazer-com-perguntas-que-podem-parecer-ser-de-desenvolvimento-mas-se-revela) ou mesmo em [O que fazer com perguntas que apenas procuram "code review for typos"?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/514/o-que-fazer-com-perguntas-que-apenas-procuram-code-review-for-typos). Porque a pergunta discutida aqui tem mais utilidade e resiste muito mais ao tempo que os tipos de perguntas discutidas nesses dois tópicos citados. Mesmo que tivesse só um link, o que não é o caso. O que está em jogo é se vamos aceitar perguntas assim ou não.

Curiosamente ela foi fechada por quem defende que nós devemos manter quase tudo aberto a não ser que a pergunta seja uma aberração. Essa pergunta está longe de ser uma aberração.

E como ela pode ser ampla demais com uma resposta tão simples? Mas aí o problema é outro e vou falar disso depois, aqui ou em uma resposta à outra discussão relevante em [O que está acontecendo com uma pergunta já resolvida?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/533/o-que-esta-acontecendo-com-uma-pergunta-ja-resolvida).

## Segunda pergunta

O mesmo vale para a [Ler registro de histórico de SMS no iPhone usando Xamarin](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2209/ler-registro-de-historico-de-sms-no-iphone-usando-xamarin). Só que foi fechada como duplicada da primeira apesar de tratar de assuntos completamente diferentes. Como teve *pelo menos* 3 pessoas que acharam uma duplicada da outra? Algo muito errado está acontecendo.

## Terceira pergunta

No caso da [Ler arquivo contatos agenda iPhone usando Xamarin](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2210/ler-arquivo-contatos-agenda-iphone-usando-xamarin) tem uma resposta do hernandes e o utluiz disse aqui que achou uma resposta facilmente. Óbvio que a pergunta não é duplicada das outras. A resposta é diferente e ela em conjunto com a pergunta ajuda definir se é duplicada ou não. Algumas pessoas não tem a menor noção do que seja uma pergunta duplicada e vamos ter que lidar com isso, vamos ter que ensinar que a pergunta precisa ser uma duplicata exata, não nas palavras, mas no que está se buscando. Não há a menor chance delas serem a mesma pergunta. É tão óbvio que eu não consigo imaginar como isso ocorreu. Bom, foi apenas figura de linguagem. As pessoas acharam que três perguntas seguidas sobre Xamarin deveriam ser feitas em uma só. Aí sim, ficaria muito ampla.

Houve até sugestão de juntar as três em uma, para, pasmem, torná-la menos ampla.

## Como lidar com as perguntas (de forma geral)

Nenhuma delas são muito amplas e as respostas mostram isso. Quem achou muito ampla provavelmente não entende do assunto e deveria se abster nesses casos.

Elas estavam mal escritas no começo? Certamente. Se fossem fechadas por não estarem claras, eu até entenderia. Mas precisamos fechar correndo?

“Ah, mas ele não se esforçou para perguntar”. Concordo. Mas vamos sair correndo e tomar uma atitude radical na hora? Não vamos dar uma chance para ele consertar? Não dá para só editar para melhorar? Vou tratar disso em outra pergunta.

Apesar de não gostar de perguntas mal feitas, gosto de dar a chance do autor ou outra pessoa tentar salvá-la. Se eu me sentir confortável, eu mesmo o faço.

Pessoalmente, eu prefiro lidar com uma pergunta que está ruim mas pode ser salva do que uma pergunta que só é útil para quem está perguntando.

Uma das perguntas ainda não foi reaberta. Para votar sem pensar, foi rápido, para consertar o erro, está bem mais difícil. Então tem que tomar cuidado com certas ações e com certos usuários que estão agindo como bem entendem sem vir aqui no meta ver o que está acontecendo.

As pessoas estão sem saber quando é para excluir, quando é para votar por um motivo ou por outro e estão votando o mais rápido que podem. Isso é ruim. Vamos ter que resolver esse problema.

Se a pergunta não está depondo contra o site ou qualquer membro, se ela não é ofensiva, se não causa problemas, não precisamos fechá-la correndo. Peço calma aos usuários experientes e aos novatos que procurem se informar melhor como usar as ferramentas disponíveis. Mas principalmente peço que evitem votar em assuntos que a pessoa desconhece ou não consegue dar um parecer adequado. É melhor deixar a pergunta do jeito que está até aparecer alguém que saiba o que fazer com ela.

## Conclusão

O que eu acho delas é que apesar de estar quase pedindo “faça pra mim” elas podem ser úteis se forem trabalhadas. Inicialmente elas eram bem isso, mas foram melhorando. Odeio perguntas “faça para mim”. Mas como está havendo uma onda de aceitar perguntas muito específicas, mais adequadas para fóruns, eu tenderia a aceitar primeiro essas perguntas para depois aceitar as mais específicas.

**Eu aprendi alguma coisa com essas três perguntas** apesar de nem usar a tecnologia.

Nos casos que não são graves, até termos regras mais claras, vamos preferir abrir uma discussão aqui no meta antes de começar agindo ativamente.

Answer (score 6):

Não quero ser muito "do contra", mas eu não consegui ver essas perguntas como "amplas demais" ou que necessitassem um tutorial como resposta.

Embora as duas primeiras sejam praticamente a mesma pergunta, para mim elas são equivalentes a algo assim:

1. Como ler um TXT no Java?
2. Como ler um TXT contendo números no Java?

A resposta poderia ser simples, direta e *diferente* para as duas situações, embora muito semelhantes. O pior que poderia acontecer são respostas diferentes, umas usando APIs mais simples que carregam o arquivo todo em memória, outras mais avançadas usando array de bytes ou leitura assíncrona, por exemplo.

Voltando ao assunto, eu fiz uma única pesquisa em Inglês por "xamarin to how access address book" e o [primeiro resultado](http://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/xamarin.mobile) traz uma solução objetiva para a questão #3. Isso demonstra, na melhor das hipóteses, que o autor da pergunta não sabe pesquisar em inglês.

Na pior das hipóteses, o autor não se esforçou para encontrar a solução por si mesmo. Mas, pesquisando por "xamarin acessar lista de contatos", não encontrei nada útil em Português.

Enfim, pode ser que eu não esteja vendo alguma (ou muita) coisa, mas simplesmente não consigo concordar com a questão das perguntas serem "amplas", embora no caso das duas primeiras acredito que sejam duplicadas no contexto em que foram feitas.

E só para deixar de nota, também não concordo com a atividade de negativar a pergunta só por ser duplicada, como parece que 3 pessoas fizeram. Já existe a funcionalidade de marcá-la como duplicada. Eu entendo que dá vontade de fazer isso porque parece que a pessoa está fazendo você perder seu tempo, mais alguns outros motivos. O problema é que se o OP não sabe usar o site ainda, isso não vai ensiná-lo. Seria interessante pelo menos dar uma chance de esclarecimento.

---

**Complemento**

*Talvez* (ou *provavelmente*), o OP pudesse ter melhorado o conteúdo e feito apenas uma pergunta explicando seu objetivo e todos ficassem contentes, mas sinceramente, com todas as perguntas sinalizadas e com todos os comentários feitos, acredito que ele fique intimidado e abandone o site.

Eu não tiro a razão do controle que todos os moderadores e usuários estão fazendo, se esforçando para criar um site de qualidade. Nas, infelizmente, essa acaba sendo, algumas vezes, a consequência deste "policiamento" minucioso. Por isso, em casos como este, eu defendo dar uma chance ao autor, aguardando um feedback dele, antes de tomar uma ação de sinalizar ou votar.

Comment: Essas perguntas claramente têm problemas de qualidade, e o que fazer com elas é a discussão que eu propus aqui. Eu acho que as três mereciam votos contra (ok, o fechamento é discutível), e deixei de dar esses votos justamente para não assustar o usuário. Outros antes de mim deixaram comentários, mas ele não se manifestou. Como vamos definir as regras deste site se vivermos sempre com medo de os outros se ofenderem? É preciso saber as opiniões da comunidade. E quem participa precisa entender que isto é um beta, e que estamos definindo como proceder.

Comment: E só esclarecendo: ninguém aqui é moderador, só o Gabe.

Comment: @bfavaretto Concordo, só coloquei meu ponto de vista para tentar influenciar numa direção que considero importante.

Comment: @bfavaretto Acabei de lembrar que o usuário se manifestou [nesta pergunta](http://br.stackoverflow.com/questions/2208/como-faco-para-ler-o-log-das-chamadas-recebidas-e-efetuadas-no-iphone-utilizando), explicando o contexto da mesma. Não digo que é o seu caso, mas o problema que vejo é algumas pessoas considerarem a pergunta ampla porque não são especialistas na tecnologia. Para um desenvolvedor Android ou iOS, uma pergunta de "como acessar a lista de contatos" não é ampla. É algo que ele faz (ou não, como o Zuul bem respondeu) no dia-a-dia e deveria saber responder "na lata". (Minha opinião)

Comment: Eu concordo que não ser especialista nessas tecnologias pesou no meu julgamento. O que mais me incomoda é a falta de empenho para perguntar. E eu vi essa a manifestação do usuário, mas achei que não acrescentou nada que ele já não houvesse dito...

Comment: @bfavaretto Entendi. Eu concordo que falta empenho mesmo. Meu problema é que ainda não me decidi em como agir por aqui. No trabalho (e em alguns fóruns) eu aprendi a ser complacente, pois infelizmente há pessoas que simplesmente não tem a capacidade (ou não se esforçam) para formular uma pergunta coerente. Provavelmente se elas tivessem, talvez não precisassem para começo de história. Já cansei de replicar: "Espere um pouco. Primeiro me explique onde você quer chegar com isso." Por experiência, posso afirmar que no dia-a-dia a maioria das perguntas estão erradas em si mesmas.

Comment: Bem, o jeito é aguardar outros comentários para ver o melhor caminho para o site.

Comment: @utluiz você poderia votar para reabrir as duas questões que faltam? Creio que já está tudo corrigido ou esclarecido. Algumas até mesmo já tem respostas.